# Session expires for user logged in by moblie app

Tags: services, sessions, cookies

I am using drupal 7 services module version 3.x. I do not want my session to be expired.
I have set ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 946080000); and ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);

This is working fine for me when I am using POSTMAN in my browser, it does not expire till I close all my browser tab and clear the cache.

When I login through mobile app my session expires after 24 hours and I receive 403 error.
How can I stop my session to expire.

Comment: You can use jdrupal.js file for connection to your drupal site. Add Drupalsitename and endpoint of service to your mobile js file. You can refer this [jdrupal](http://jdrupal.easystreet3.com/7/docs/Introduction). Then Session not expire until you close app.

Comment: I do not want the session to be closed until user calls drupal logout service. I want it to get handled through Drupal end. Note: I am using drupal as backend and mobile app is used for accessing the drupal services only.

Comment: I am using drupal 7

Comment: You can try DrupalGap module. But I am sure about session storage till logout. You can use jdrupal and store user data in local storage. If local storage available then login again with user data else display login page. In this way session not expire.

Comment: Thanks but I am just exposing drupal services to mobile app which are not in drupal and I can not add drupal code over there

Comment: I am not sure but you can try local storage in html5 to store session.

Comment: I debugged the issue and found out that the issue is coming only when I am trying to access the services from IOS devices like iPhone and iPad. the user is getting a header response cookie expired

Comment: To solve this issue I added session expire module and added session age as Never